# Не запускается Docker контейнер

Tags: python, docker, flask, framework

Использую следующую команду для запуска контейнера
`docker run --name website -d -p 8000:5000 website:latest`

(при параметре --rm контейнер и вовсе не создается)

Контейнер виден в приложении, но при попытке запустить его, процесс мгновенно прерывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

следующим образом выглядит сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:stretch

RUN useradd website

WORKDIR /HealthPredict

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv HAWVenv
RUN HAWVenv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN HAWVenv/bin/pip install gunicorn pymysql

COPY website/app website/app
COPY website/migrations website/migrations
COPY website/website.py website/config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP website/website.py

RUN chown -R website:website ./
USER website

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

При просмотре логов наблюдаю следующее:

```
./boot.sh: 2: ./boot.sh: source: not found
./boot.sh: 3: ./boot.sh: flask: not found
./boot.sh: 4: ./boot.sh: flask: not found
./boot.sh: 5: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

Сам файлик boot.sh выглядит следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/sh
source HAWVenv/bin/activate
flask db upgrade
flask translate compile
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - website:app
```

При замене на `#!/bin/bash` в логах наблюдаю `Error: No such command 'translate'.`, что относится к flask, хотя у flask определенно есть такой метод

Comment: Ну значит читайте логи и ищите, кто где почему внутри контейнера завершает работу

Comment: @andreymal Я понял, что вы имели ввиду. Внес правку в описание проблемы

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `source` на `.` (точку)

Comment: А лучше наверно вообще выкинуть включение виртуального окружения и напрямую запускать команды `HAWVenv/bin/flask` и `HAWVenv/bin/gunicorn` соответственно

Comment: (да и вообще зачем городить виртуальное окружение внутри контейнера, но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: Попробовал замену - не вышло( 
`ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:stretch `
А виртуальное окружение не могу откинуть, так как туда подгружается файлик, в котором большое количество различных модулей-версий

Comment: Замена банального source на банальную точку в банальном файле не может вызвать ошибку такого рода, вероятно вы сломали что-то ещё

Comment: Я просто в этом плане зеленый совсем) Но идея такая: хочу залить контейнер на хостинг. И будет странно если автоматически не будут подгружаться все модули, которые используются в проекте

Comment: Еще раз все пересобрал с заменой source как вы и посоветовали, но проблема все та же(
Имею ввиду главную проблему, по которой и вопрос собственно

Answer (score 0):

> при параметре --rm контейнер и вовсе не создается

Контейнер создаётся, но вы не успеваете это заметить. При опции `--rm` докер создаёт временный контейнер. В этом контейнере докер запускает скрипт `boot.sh`. Когда скрипт завершается, докер удаляет временный контейнер.

Почему завершается `boot.sh` раньше, чем вы ожидали, написано в логах

```
./boot.sh: 2: ./boot.sh: source: not found
```

В шелле `/bin/sh` нет команды `source`, поэтому ваше виртуальное окружение не активируется, как следствие скрипт не находит ни `flask`, ни `gunikorn`, и завершается с ошибкой.

Вам следует либо поменять первую строку на `#!/bin/bash`, либо вместо `source` использовать `.`

Comment: По какой-то причине при замене на bash происходит следующая ошибка:
`Error: No such command 'translate'.`
сама команда `translate` используется в flask`е